# Can you iterate through all objects under an abstract class in PHP?

Tags: php, loops, class, abstract

Rephrased: can you iterate through all child objects instantiated from classes that are under an abstract class?

Comment: Not quite clear what you're going for. What is the actual goal (use case) of this?

Comment: I want a list of every object in a abstract class.

Comment: You mean a list of any variables that hold an object of a class that extends the abstract class?

Comment: Given only the name of the abstract class I want to iterate through all classes and objects under it for purposes of making a list or updating properties in each object. Possible?